# upgrading to react router v5 from v4 onEnter is now deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some code where I'm rendering some components in react based off a current route

```
import Confirmation from './containers/Confirmation';

...

ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} onUpdate={scrollToTop}>
      <Route exact path={BASKET} component={Main} />
      <Route path={DELIVERY} component={Main} />
      <Route path={ADDRESS} component={Main} />
      <Route path={COMPLETE} component={Confirmation} onEnter={checkOrderComplete(store)} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('checkout-target')
);

...

const checkOrderComplete = (store) => (nextState, replace) => {
  const state = store.getState();

  const orderCompleted = state.basket.pubOrderNumber !== '';

  if (!orderCompleted) {
    Logger.error(`incomplete order ➜ redirect to ${BASKET}`);

    replace({ pathname: BASKET });
  }
};
```

`onEnter` is no longer working since upgrading to v5. How can I achieve the same functionality with the upgraded version?

Comment: You just want to guard access to the route and redirect to `pathname: BASKET` if the order is not completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a protected route component that does the check when it mounts. The idea here is that the custom route accesses the Redux store and computes the `orderCompleted` derived state value and conditionally returns the route content or redirects to the basket route.

Something like the following.

```
const CompletedRoute = props => {
  const state = store.getState();

  const orderCompleted = state.basket.pubOrderNumber !== '';

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!orderCompleted) {
      Logger.error(`incomplete order ➜ redirect to ${BASKET}`);
    }
  }, [orderCompleted]);

  return orderCompleted ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: BASKET }} />
  );
};
```

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} onUpdate={scrollToTop}>
      <Route exact path={BASKET} component={Main} />
      <Route path={DELIVERY} component={Main} />
      <Route path={ADDRESS} component={Main} />
      <CompletedRoute path={COMPLETE} component={Confirmation} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('checkout-target')
);
```